# What are exact scenarios when Azure DownloadToFileAsync task ends with Http status code 206 (Partial Contswnt) in last result?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

So far I've found only one case: change active wi-fi network during execution of DownloadToFileAsync. [Microsoft Docs only says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob):

> A successful operation to read the full blob returns status code 200 (OK).
>
> A successful operation to read a specified range returns status code 206 (Partial Content).

And that's all I was able to get from docs.

Despite docs, when I'm changing wi-fi network during downloading task execution, I always get 206 status code in LastResult. I wonder if anyone faced the same case.

Comment: Isn't 206 always the response code if storage returns a part of the file and not the whole file? The SDK requests the file in chunks by default if it is larger than X bytes.

Comment: @juunas, I've also checked file - it is complete. After wi-fy network change download task perform retry, downloads whole file and after that ends with 206 status code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 206 status is a HTTP standard. As the documentation says, it indicates that you successfully read a specified range of data from your resource. Which means that you have to indicate a range in you original request.

You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://httpstatuses.com/206).

You'll notice that the header of the answer will also indicate the specified range.

**EDIT** : I realized that I did not really answer the question.

You can trigger the 206 code when requesting a partial resource from the GetBlob API. There is a 'Range' request header that you can use for that.

Regarding the behaviour that you observed while switching WiFi network, I guess that is linked to the fact that since your client managed to download only the first part of the document before losing connection, it had to request for the final range of the document when retrieving the connection, thus getting the 206 status code.

Comment: Thank you for idea, I've also some kind of similar thought. What I hope to find is the exact document, mentioning such/similar scenario.