# File is not downloading using DownloadToAsyc method

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, console-application

I am trying to download a file from azure blob storage using the console app but it is not working well. I am getting 206 responses from DownloadToAsync() method. I am not getting any exceptions, but it's not getting downloaded either. Below are some code snippets.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(localFilePath); //localFilePath is path of file
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient("connectionstring","containerName");
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
var response = await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(localFilePath);
```

In response, I am getting a 206 status code. I have tried the same without async as well but still no luck.

Comment: Have you checked [What are exact scenarios when Azure DownloadToFileAsync task ends with Http status code 206 (Partial Content) in last result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870041/what-are-exact-scenarios-when-azure-downloadtofileasync-task-ends-with-http-stat) ? Was the connection interrupted perhaps? You can use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what's actually going on over the network. Perhaps some requests timed out>

Comment: Yes, I checked this link and seems 206 is they return which is not the issue. That post does not help me well. I don't know I am confused what need to be done

Comment: It *is* the issue and you're asking why the *overall* operation returns 206 The method executes multiple partial requests in parallel. All those will get a 206 HTTP response. If all succeed, the `Response` object will have Status =200. If some of them fail you'll get 206. Which means that either *some* of the requests failed, or the operation itself stopped for some reason before it could send all the requests it needed.

Comment: You should probably use [the overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadto?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-specialized-blobbaseclient-downloadto(system-string-azure-storage-blobs-models-blobdownloadtooptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) that allows you to specify a progress handler and transfer options to see what's going on and change the number of parallel downloads and chunk sizes

Comment: I have tried giving transfer options as mentioned in this snippet [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-download-files?tabs=dotnet) I got the same status 206 but with that, I got another statusCode "Ran to completion". The file could not downloaded.

Comment: And what was reported? Yes, you can't download the file, you wrote that from the start. What is going on? Did you get any progress events? Were any requests made? Nobody can help you without any information. `I got another statusCode "Ran to completion"` there's no such HTTP status code. That's the `Task.Status` value of a completed task, not the `Response.Status`

Comment: I am getting status 206 only and contentStream null, isError false, ReasonPhrase partial content

Comment: Please don't repeat what you wrote from the start. Did you actually add a progress handler? Was anything reported? And *did you actually use Fiddler*? What did you see there? `Yes, there are requests` is meaningless. How many, how did they end, how big is the file, did those requests cover the entire range?

Comment: Can you download that file in any other way? If [downloading with the CLI doesn't work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-cli#download-a-blob), your code won't work either

Comment: I have added a progress tracker as explained in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67817675/display-upload-progress-to-azure-blob) and in cmd, I can see " Bytes Uploaded 14952" and I checked in headers content length was 14952 only

Comment: Issue is resolved. I was giving wrong path of folder :P

Comment: @Dhanashri Could you provide an answer, and provide some details.  I'm having the same problem and my path I think is fine, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Just so others know, this can occur because of your controller method that initializes the code you show above.  I had this error because in my controller I was using `async Task<IActionResult>` in the method signature and in this same controller method I was returning Ok().  I shouldn't have been returning anything because I was using the http response like this:  `await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(response.Body);`   I guess returning OK, was causing the browser to think I was done with the transfer even though it wasn't.  My controller method should have use this signature:  `async Task`

Answer (score 0):

**206** also indicates that **blob file is too large**, You can try as below:

```
var options = new StorageTransferOptions
{
    MaximumTransferLength = 4 * 1024 * 1024, // Set the maximum transfer length if needed
    MaximumConcurrency = 4, // Adjust concurrency based on your requirements
};

var response = await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(localFilePath, options);
```